# An SqlParameter with ParameterName is not contained?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a problem with something I have done many times but this time it just doesn't work.

This is what what I am trying to do (in Visual Studio 2003 and VB.NET)

Earlier in the code:

```
Private SaveCustomerInformationCommand As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
```

Then this in a setup process:

```
SaveCustomerInformationCommand = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("spSaveCustomerInformation")
SaveCustomerInformationCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
Dim custIdParameter As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter = SaveCustomerInformationCommand.CreateParameter()
custIdParameter.ParameterName = "@CustId"
custIdParameter.SqlDbType = Data.SqlDbType.Int
custIdParameter.Direction = Data.ParameterDirection.Input
SaveCustomerInformationCommand.Parameters.Add(custIdParameter)
```

And then later:

```
SaveCustomerInformationCommand.Parameters.Item("@CustId").Value = myValue
```

And I get this:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@CustId' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.
```

Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Is anything else tampering with the `Parameters` collection?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the "@" is not technically part of the name of the parameter... rather it's what you put into your T-SQL to denote that a parameter name is coming afterwards.  So I think you'll want to refer to it like this instead (with no "@") :

```
SaveCustomerInformationCommand.Parameters.Item("CustId").Value = myValue
```

You could also try the same thing when you initially insert the parameter name-- although since you're not getting an error there, I'd suspect the accessor call is to blame, not the inserter call.